# Two Reflecting Barriers

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes

A chain with stats 1,2,....,n has a matrix whose first and last rows are (*q,p,*0,...,0) and (0,...,0*,q,p*). In all other rows P<sub>k,k+1</sub> = *p*, P<sub>k,k-1</sub> = *q*. Find the stationary distribution.

I am completely stuck. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is arch-classical. What did you try?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**.  You need $\def\\#1{{\bf#1}}P\\v=\\v$, that is, $(P-I)\\v=\\0$.  Now
$$P-I=\pmatrix{-p&p&0&0&0&\cdots\cr q&-1&p&0&0&\cdots\cr 0&q&-1&p&0&\cdots\cr
  \vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots\cr}\ .$$
(I am assuming that $p+q=1$ although you didn't actually say so.)  You want to multiply this by a vector $\\v=(v_1,v_2,v_3,\ldots)^T$ to get the zero vector as a result.  Now if you look at row $1$ you see straight away that $v_1=v_2$.  Then row $2$ will tell you about $v_3$ and so on.  Once you have got to the end of the matrix you will need to find the specific values for $v_1,v_2,v_3,\ldots$ such that $\\v$ is a probability vector, that is, the entries add up to $1$.

Good luck!